# Selecting a particular column from dataTable and updating values in all the rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm currently selecting a bunch of values from SQL and load them into a dataTable. I'm trying to find that particular column and update the value in each rows.

```
Dim dt as DataTable
'not all code is included - but this definitely works on selecting data
sql = " Select value1, value2, value3 from TblA "
cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
dt.Load(reader)
return dt
```

My goal is to take the value from each row in VALUE3, and run it through a small Formatting function called - UpdateFormat. Something along the lines of....

```
Dim specValue As String
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
      UpdateFormat(specValue ) = row.Item("Value3")
Next row
```

I'm hoping to update each value and update the dataTable so it has the correct values.

Comment: are you wanting to **change** value3 or create that formatted thing from whatever is in value3 and save to a new column - I would initially suggest the latter so that anything else somewhere that needs it UNformatted can still have access to it.

Comment: @plutonix I want to UPDATE value3 and leave it in the same column. Basically take each row from column "Value3" and update it with my UpdateFormat function. sorry if i'm not clear. Nothing else will need it unformatted - I only use that dataset/datatable for my reports.

Comment: My question related to the scope of this.  Are you ***sure*** nothing will break if you change/format value3 as opposed to creating a new column and saving the formatted value there?

Comment: @plutonix - yes i am certain. :)

Comment: Then you should just be able to run an UPDATE query once you work out the exact SubStr machinations

Comment: @plutonix - I don't know if i understand you correctly. I basically want to update the DataTable. I don't want to update SQLServer - the values there are stored as varchar. I want to grab them, update the dataTable that I've just loaded and then use that datatable as my recordSource for my rdlc report. Nothing else is dependent on this DataTable/value. This is explicitly used for a single report. I'm having a hard time looping through the rows of a particular column

Comment: Ahh, that wasnt clear.  Please clarify "a hard time"  where is the result supposed to go?  back to value3?

Comment: @plutonix - yes, so take row1 from value3 - the run through the function UpdateFormat - update that row in Value3. Take next row and update it. or however is easier. I want to take all values from Value3 - re-format then and then re-load them into Value3.

Comment: inside your loop: `row("Value3") = ApplyFormat(row.Field(Of String)("Value3"))`

Comment: What doesn't make since is you want to give special formatting to each record for a specific column as soon as you fill the table... Why do it ***after*** when you can do it in SQL so it's already formatted, that makes more sense and cuts out grunt work that can go wrong... Just my two cents... What is `UpdateFormat` anyways I see it takes a string and maybe updates a specific item to match value 3.. and that still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @zaggler it's a hand written function that looks kinda like this....Mid(Value_ID, 1, 3) + "-" + Mid(Value_ID, 4, 2) + "-"...........so i think it's safer to run it once I have the data in the table - it's a specific format that I have to use

Comment: @plutonix - thanks this did it

Comment: Six to Five and Pick-em.  You can do those ops in SQL

Comment: It seems to work fine like this - I'll leave it for now. You can always post as answer @plutonix - and ill accept

Comment: `select Id, CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Value3],1,3), 
            '-',
                  SUBSTRING([Value3],4,2),
            '-',
      SUBSTRING([Value3],6,4),
      'W'
      ) AS NewV3Value from dbo.TableBob;`

Comment: @plutonix provded two answers - te only thing I can do is accept your answer so go aheadddddd!

Comment: You need a hat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a previous episode, we learned that you want to format the data in that column from `012345678` to `012-34-5678W` where the column is VarChar and the 'W' is fixed.

You can do the formatting in the SQL:

```
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT Id, Foo, Bar, ColA, 
                    CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Value3],1,3), 
                            '-', 
                        SUBSTRING([Value3],4,2), 
                        '-', 
                        SUBSTRING([Value3],6,4), 
                        'W' ) AS NewV3Value 
                FROM 
                    dbo.TableBob
          </sql>.Value
```

Doing so, the column is delivered to you already formatted.  Depending on your DB flavor, the exact syntax may vary.

The `<sql>...</sql>.Value` is just an XML literal which allows you to format long or complex queries in such a way that it makes it easier for you to read.

To do it yourself in the table.  As the format is trivial to apply, you really dont need a method to do it:

```
Dim tmp As String
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    tmp = row.Field(Of String)("Value3")
    row("Value3") = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}W", 
                                     tmp.Substring(0, 3),
                                     tmp.Substring(3, 2),
                                     tmp.Substring(5, 4))
Next row
```

The `tmp` var is just to shorten the code.